# Exchange 2010 unable to add security group via command line

Tags: security, permissions, exchange

Hi I have created a Security group that is Universal. Added users to this security group. 
In Exchange, add a new distribution group and select this new Security group as the target group. After the group has been enabled as an "email enabled security group" I have tried to assign permissions for the person's calender to the group using this command:

```
add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity USERID:\Calendar -User Sercuritygroupname -AccessRights Owner
```

However over and over again it keeps saying in RED

> "The operation couldn't be performed because 'USERID:\Calendar'
>   couldn't be found.

I just replace the USERID with one of my mailbox aliasses or AD user name, both aren't accepted.. or it doesn't really like the calendar behind?

What might be wrong? any ideas?

Comment: I dug up a script I've used for this and I used this format so give it a shot and use the backtick character too -- or try with and without the backtick actually `Add-MailboxFolderPermission "domain\calendar:\Calendar" -User "domain\securitygroup" -AccessRights Owner`

Comment: The backtick I was referring to did not list in the comment so here's a screen shot to clarify what I'm referring to: https://i.imgur.com/lOE6uRP.png. Please note that this is the syntax I've used with success for this task with Exchange 2010 as well so it should work. I'm not sure if you need to omit the `-identity` parameter or if the backtick makes any difference or if not specifying the domain name will do it, but my script is dynamic but this is the command it builds regardless.

Comment: Not sure if I can reply on your suggestion? But I just want to know what do you mean with the first "domain\calendar" line? I suppose you need to fill in the user mailbox here? so do you mean domain\user or do you mean instead of domain just type user name here? If that's the case I don't understand why you do need to add domain for the security group here too.?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I did mean `DomainName\UserName`... Apologies, please let me know how it goes if that helps you any `Add-MailboxFolderPermission "domain\username:\Calendar" -User "domain\securitygroup" -AccessRights Owner`

Comment: thanks; I did try your new command, but no success (yet). I did try with or without the backtick symbol... both resulting in the same.

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>add-mailboxfolderpermission "domain\user`:\Calendar" -User "domain\security group" -accessrights publishingeditor

The operation couldn't be performed because 'domain\user:\Calendar' couldn't be found.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 6A26AC30,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.AddMailboxFolderPermission

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try to use `"username@domainname.com:\Calendar"` instead for that specific part of the PowerShell logic and tell me if that helps. Otherwise, can you confirm the language this server is running such as English, Spanish, etc.?

Comment: I tried and same. however I am a bit further.. I mean I tried a dummy user who doesn't exist and the error changes.. (as you can see); so it  must be related to the calendar which doesnt exist or cannot be found as you can see.  As far as I can tell it's English installed version.. all commands are English.

[PS] C:\Windows\system32>add-mailboxfolderpermission "dummy@domain.com`:\Calendar" -User "domain\security group" -accessrights publishingeditor

The specified mailbox "dummy@domain.com" doesn't exist.

so we have mailbox doesn't exist and 'calendar' couldn't be found.

Comment: This got me thinking... and while Exchange 2010 is English, our Outlook boxes /user-end are in Dutch... when I changed calendar for agenda it worked like a charm! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Hi ; but yes of course. That's no problem, I can accept one of the answers. For the moment I don't see the 'v' to accept any to be honest. But I looks like you need to do something first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Localized Spelling of the Exchange Calendar Subfolder

So the issue appears to be related to the hard-coded `username:calendar` in your script since the localized name of the calendar in the user's mailbox has a different spelling than you're using.

So rather than the spelling of `username:calendar` the spelling could be `username:kalendar` or `username:agenda` depending on the language localization.

Below are some method with reference to get the spelling of the calendar subfolder without actually knowing the localized spelling of the object; you can plug the result into your command(s) accordingly, or potentially build the command(s) to get it dynamically based on the [DistinguishedFolderId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580808(v=exchg.140)), etc.

> ### Get-MailboxCalendarFolder
>
> ```
> Get-MailboxCalendarFolder -Identity <MailboxFolderIdParameter> [-DomainController <Fqdn>]
> ```
>
> **Detailed Description**
>
> The **Get-MailboxCalendarFolder** cmdlet retrieves information for the
>   specified calendar folder. This information includes ***the calendar
>   folder name***, whether the folder is currently published or shared,
>   the start and end range of calendar days published, the level of
>   details published for the calendar, whether the published URL of the
>   calendar can be searched on the Web, and the published URL for the
>   calendar.
>
> <sub>[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351185(v=exchg.141).aspx)</sub>

---

> ### Powershell get default calendar name
>
> A way to get the name of the default calendar folder without checking
>   the regional or language properties.
>
> ```
> Get-mailbox | Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -FolderScope calendar | sort-object Name | ft Identity,Name
> ```
>
> ---
>
> If the User has several Calendars in Mailbox I've got multiple
>   objects. You must iterate through all of them, or filter them with
>   'where-object' to get just the default calendar.
>
> ```
> $calname = Get-MailboxFolderStatistics -Identity $username  -FolderScope calendar | where-object {$_.FolderType -eq "Calendar"}
> $calandar= $username + ":\" + $calname.Name.toString()
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/2fd043d3-9cc7-4134-a09c-1e87179f42a1/powershell-get-default-calendar-name?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy)</sub>

---

> ### Finding the name of the Calendar folder
>
> When setting permissions on your users' Calendar folders to allow (or
>   disallow) them to view each others Free/Busy status, you may encounter
>   the problem that a user has localized the folder names and you don’t
>   know what the name of the folder is in his/her language. Even worse;
>   you’re doing this in a script, that’s just using the
>   `username:\Calendar` label.
>
> The solution here is to not use hard coded names but ***instead detect
>   the name of the folder and use it in your script (or command line)***.
>   To make that really simple, you can use this bit of PowerShell code:
>
> ```
> $path = $user.Identity + ":\" + (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $user.Identity | Where-Object { $_.Foldertype -eq "Calendar" } | Select-Object -First 1).Name
>
> Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $path -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails
> ```
>
> The first line will search the MailboxFolderStatistics for folders of
>   the type “Calendar” and return the first match.
>
> Second line will use the variable `$path` to set `AccessRights` on the
>   folder regardless of localization.
>
> The `$user` variable could have been populated with Get-User or an
>   input file.
>
> <sub>[source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kpalmvig/2014/10/10/office-365-finding-the-name-of-the-calendar-folder/)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [DistinguishedFolderId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580808(v=exchg.140))
- [Get-MailboxCalendarFolder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351185(v=exchg.141).aspx)